# Padding bottom or Y-axis does not work if greater than 10 (pb-10)

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to style a form that is encapsulated in this code:

```
<div class="flex flex-row py-10">
  <div class="basis-2/12"></div>
  <div class="basis-4/6">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="basis-2/12"></div>
</div>
```

So, if instead of `py-10` I write `pt-10` and `pb-10` then I get the padding. But if I use `pb-14` or `pb-16`, bottom padding is gone. Same with `py-` with any value, there is just no padding displayed.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong or not understanding about CSS in general?

Answer (score 0):

these are working fine, I have tested it and attached the screenshots of the output here. If you still have any query or issue, please share the exact code and issue with me.

Thanks

[pb-16 and py-14 are working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl49r.png)

[I tested by adding bg color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr29q.png)

Comment: This leads me to think there is something else that I am missing, because for me it's not working, I guess a combination with some other property being set. Will update my question with more details.

Comment: Sure, I will happy to help you.